# Create modal alert instead of page redirect validation in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to have server side validation. Is there a way how can I have the alert like [this image](http://2nwl40151nra3yah86118nxtto0.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/Screen-Shot-2013-04-30-at-2.06.13-AM.png) whenever the user input the data like email that exist in my database, the alert will appear when I hit the sumbit button. Thanks in advance. :D

Here's my create_acc.html

```
<form action="create_acc.php" method="POST" id="fieldform">
    <dl>
    <p><dt>Email Address:</dt>
    <dd>
    <input type="text" name="e-mail" id="e-mail" class="text" placeholder="Your Email will be your log in" autocomplete="off">
    </dd>
    </p>

    <p><dt>Create Password:</dt>
    <dd>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="text" placeholder="Remember your password" autocomplete="off">
    </p>
    <p>
    <p><dt>Your Complete name:</dt>
    <dd>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text" placeholder="Your Complete name" autocomplete="off">
    </p>
    <p>
    <dt>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </dt>
    </p>
    </dl>
</form>
```

Here's my create_acc.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$email = $_POST['e-mail'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$pass = $_POST['password'];

$hash = hash('sha256',$pass);

function createSalt(){
    $text = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return substr($text,0,3);
}

$salt = createSalt();
$pass = hash('sha256',$salt.$hash);

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydb');

$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$email);

$query = "INSERT INTO customers(Email,Password,Name,salt) VALUES('$email','$pass','$name','$salt')";

mysqli_query($conn,$query);

mysqli_close($conn);

header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

Comment: You should read more about [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Hi Cyclone. I'm just a newbie eh :( Can you help me fix this?

Comment: On the submit event for you form, send an ajax request with the form data to your php file, the php file in turn will return a respons that tells if the email existed or not, then you can check this value to deside if you should display a popup or not.

Comment: Put the Image into a link so that the text looks cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to do this. When the user submits the form you would send an ajax request with the form data to your php script, the script will then respond with a value that you use to deside if you should display an alert or not, here is a basic example using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // catch submit events for your form
  $('#your-form-id').submit(function() {
    // make an ajax request to your validation script
    $.ajax{(
      url:'create_acc.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:$(this).serialize(),
      dataType:'json',
      success:function(response) {
        if(!response.success) {
          alert('Something went wrong!');
        }
      }
     });
     return false;
   });
  });
```

Then in your php script you return a code telling the client how it went:

```
  // create_acc.php
  // I assume the form only has one value 'email'
  $success = false;
  if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    // here you would check if the email already
    // exists in the database
    $query = "SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE email = ?";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['email']);
    // execute the query and check if a row was returned
  }
  // if everything went fine you should change success to true

  // return json response to client
  $response = array('success' => $success);
  print json_encode($response);
  exit;
```

Comment: Sir Cyclone. I'll try it later when I arrive at home. I'm not sure if it will run on my side but I'll try it. But for now, I'm gonna "Check" you answer. Thank you sir Cyclone... :) I'll just message you if I run it the execute properly or execute error. Thank you sir! I'll study your answer. God bless!

Comment: This is more like an example and not a complete solution. My advice would be to read up on `ajax` and also `prepared statements` in `mysqli`

Comment: I'm not too familiar sir in prepared statements... But I do know some of the mysqli statements. What's the differences between them?

Comment: @truelogicINC - Prepared statements are available in `mysqli` as I show in the above example. They can be used to secure input from the user as I also show in the above example.